# Annotation @Value is not working in my service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have my main configuration

```
    @EnableScheduling
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "gr.citystore.web.helios.yeastar" })
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
    public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private MyServiceImpl myService;

        @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
        public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
            MyThread mThread = new MyThread(myService);
        }
}
```

And my service the code is:

```
@Service("myService")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

    @Value("${property.api.ip}")
    private String apiIP;
    @Value("${property.api.port}")
    private String apiPort;

    public String myMethod() {

    }

}
```

My problem is that the @Value annotation is not working when I pass it as argument in myThread, instead is return "${property.api.port}".
What I am missing here?

EDIT:
The application.properties file location is "src/main/resources" and the content is:

```
property.api.ip = 12.34.50.30
property.api.port = 50034
```

Comment: You should show us the content of the properties file and where it resides in your code

Comment: Do you have a `static` bean definition for a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`? Without the `@Value` won't get replaced.

Comment: @M.Deinum in the Controllers MyService is working fine. I don't have a static definition for  a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: Then you have multiple instances of your service and/or are creating a new instance yourself. Also you should be injecting `MyService` insteadof the actual class, as you have defined an interface you should use that in places where you need it, instead of the concrete class. Finally remove `@PropertySource`  from your service as you already have it on the configuration.

Comment: Remove @PropertySource from your MyServiceImpl class and try to run.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have remove the PropertySource and working! But if I use the Interface to inject it, I have the same problem!

Comment: Hence you have multiple instances of the bean in places where there isn't a proper resolution. If an `@Value` cannot be resolved the application will simply break as it won't start. I strongly suggest to add the aformentions static bean definition for a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and see what happens. I would also suggest to move the field inject to consturctor injection and put that in a regular component instead of an `@Configuration`class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I fix it like you said, I create a Interface to injecting! Can you please create an anwser to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You could just inject the values of the application.properties into your class like this:

```
@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

    private final String apiIP;

    private final String apiPort;

    public MyServiceImpl(@Value("${property.api.ip}") String apiIP,
              @Value("${property.api.port}") apiPort) {
         this.apiIP = apiIP;
         this.apiPort = apiPort;
    }

    public String myMethod() {

    }

}
```